# csv to OrderedDict

Tags: python

How can I make OrderedDict from csv? Is there any function?

csv:

```
1 one
2 two
```

OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict((('1', 'one'), ('2', 'two')))
```

Comment: Read about the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) from the standard library, and follow the examples there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your csv has two columns as described in your question, you can do this:

```
import csv
import collections

with open('foo.csv','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = collections.OrderedDict(r)
```

If the rows in the csv file were formatted as `key, value1, value2, value3` you would do this:

```
with open('foo.csv','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = collections.OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, the CSV module can import a CSV file and convert rows directly to instances of `OrderedDict`, with the order of the keys consistent with your CSV file. This is a departure from Python 2 behavior where the rows were returned as plain dict types.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open(filename) as fd:
    for row in csv.DictReader(fd):
        pprint(row)
```

```
Date,Name,Notes
31 May 2019,Robert,
1 June 2019,Silvio,
```

```
OrderedDict([('Date', '31 May 2019'),
             ('Name', 'Robert'),
             ('Notes', '')])
OrderedDict([('Date', '1 June 2019'),
             ('Name', 'Silvio'),
             ('Notes', '')])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, easy way was to subclass and tweak a csv function.  Here is my working bit of code: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577996-ordered-csv-read-write-with-colum-based-lookup/?in=user-4177968

Answer (score 0):

There's a csv module that includes a reader.  In general, you can turn a list of tuples into a dictionary like so:

```
d = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in listOfTuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution is accepted, my alternative solution would suit the situation where the key can be located in any columns::

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> csv = pe.Sheet("your.csv", name_rows_by_column=0)
>>> your_dict = csv.to_dict() # Voila, OrderredDict in return!
```

where [name_rows_by_column](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/v0.0.9/generated/pyexcel.load.html#pyexcel.load) can be any index of the available columns.